# IRC (rfc1459): Which event says that I am connected?

Tags: python, irc

I am just about to implement some parts of `rfc1459`.

My thing is:

how do I know that my script is correctly connected to the network. I mean what event says your "yes sir. you pass all my inspections, go ahead"

I'm currently check if there occurs the message ":Welcome" :3

```
if ':Welcome' in s:
        print 'Connection established...'
        self.send('JOIN %s\r\n' % self.channel)
```

Comment: Dump the RFC and inspect an actual IRCd. The RFC isn't really adhered to very well.

Comment: What am I supposed to do with IRCd? I need a good client implementation. But good point I am figuring it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured it out!

My first issue is that there is an rfc that updates the rfc1459: [rfc2812](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812)

lo and behold there is a welcome message RPL_WELCOME.

Thats exactly what I want to know!

- Timo